# Mutual friends between 3 people

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to get the number of mutual friends that any particular friend I have shares with my friends. So for example,

```
My friends = Joe Bob Steve Bill
Joe's friends = me Bob Steve John
Bob's friends = me Joe Steve Bill John
```

I have 2 mutual friends with Joe (Bob, Steve) and 3 with Bob. Joe and Bob also have 3 mutual friends (me, Steve, John) but I am only friends with 1 of those people (Steve). That 1 is the number I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with FQL - if you know the Facebook ids for Joe and Bob:

```
SELECT 
    uid1 
FROM 
    friend 
WHERE 
    uid1 IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = JOE_ID)
AND 
    uid1 IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = BOB_ID) 
AND 
    uid2 = me();
```

This will return you the ID for Steve.